# Update row after insert from a another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I use MySql and have two tables, `master` and `inventory`. Now I need a trigger after insert update inventory table field `product_description` from `master` table field `product_description`.

Example:

**master table:**

```
pmid  -  product_name - product_description - price
1        tv                HD tv               10
```

**inventory table:**

```
invid - pmid  - product_description - color
1        1                             black
```

Trigger should insert product_description from `partmaster` where pmid = pmid.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `master` (
  `pmid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pmid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory` (
  `invid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pmid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `color` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invid`),
  KEY `pmid` (`pmid`),   //foreign key master table//
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER update_inventory AFTER INSERT ON master
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE inventory I SET I.product_description = new.product_description 
WHERE (I.pmid = new.pmid );
END; //
delimiter ;
```

I find your data inconsistent:
1. How can you have pmid in inventory without having it in master table? 
2. Color field is numeric; contradicts your example.